# how to replace a row of a matrix with another row of different length in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 2X3 matrix. I want to replace row#2 (which is three columns wide) with another row which is two columns wide. I am okay if the new row has NaN in the third column.

For example in this code x is two columns wide and I want to replace row two of the matrix "list" with x.

```
list=[1,2,3;4,5,3];
if numel(setdiff(list(1,:),list(2,:)))~=0;
x=setdiff(list(1,:),list(2,:));
list(2,:)=x; %this is where i get error
end
```

thanks

Comment: Just pad your vector `x` with enough `NaN` by calculating the difference between the number of rows in `list` and the length of  `x` :

`list(2,:)=[x NaN(1,size(list,2)-length(x))];`

If you still got the error, check that `x` is indeed a row vector and not a column vector

Comment: @BillBokeey ! difference between number of **columns*** (not rows). Your solution is correct although ! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your new value is always smaller than the original one, you could try this:

```
list=[1,2,3;4,5,3];
if numel(setdiff(list(1,:),list(2,:)))~=0;
     x=setdiff(list(1,:),list(2,:));
     list(2,:)=nan(size(list(2,:)));
     list(2,1:length(x))=x; 
end
```

However, I do not really like this solution, since it is not rubust. I prefer working with cell structures:

```
list=[{[1,2,3]};{[4,5,3]}];
if numel(setdiff(list{1,:},list{2,:}))~=0;
   x=setdiff(list{1,:},list{2,:});
   list{2,:} = [];
   list{2,:}=x; %length of this row is now arbitrary
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the erroneous line with this:

```
list(2,:)=[x NaN*ones(1,size(list,2)-size(x,2))]
```

Here you are comparing the columns of `list` and `x`. A matrix of **1xdifference_of_columns** is formed comprising of all ones which is then multiplied with `NaN` and thus a matrix is formed with the same order and all elements as `NaN` which is then appended with x to create a row with the same number of columns as that of original `list` matrix.